# How to preserve authorship of a forked repository on GitHub?

Tags: open-source, copyright

Say, a repository licensed under BSD-2 license has been forked on GitHub. A major refactoring is happening and new features are going to be added. No interactions with the original repository is expected in the future.

What should/could happen with the original author's name present in the source code? Should the fork maintainer's name be just added above the original author's name in the LICENSE file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The maintainer of the fork must do what it says in the license text, which is to preserve the copyright notice and license text in all files that contain substantial quantities of the original code. In practice, this means all files. The maintainer of the fork may also as add their own notices/terms/etc as they wish (or not, if they prefer) - the BSD license has nothing to say on this matter.

Comment: Assuming that the license remains the same, then new contributors' names are just being added above the original copyright notice, correct?

Comment: That's the most common approach, yes.